# Showing $\{0\}\cup\{ 1/k: k\in \mathbb{N} \}$ are the only cluster points of $\{ \frac 1n + \frac 1m : n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen different responses to this here, but I wanted to write up an answer in my own terms.

Definition for cluster point:

> $E$ metric space and $A \subset E$.
>
> $x \in E$ is a cluster point of $A$ iff each ball with center $x$ has infinitely many points from $A$.

The definition above of cluster point is equivalent to that of limit point (each ball having a point in $A$ different from the center).

Below is my attempt, all feedback is welcomed.

---

**Proof**:

For each element in $A = \{ \frac 1n + \frac 1m: n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$, either $n \geq m$ or $m \geq n$. In what follows I will without loss of generality always assume $n \geq m$.

If $r \in A$ then $r = \frac 1n + \frac 1m \leq \frac 2m \leq 1 $ for all $n \geq m \geq 2$. So only finitely many points of $A$ are in the interval $[1,2]$ which rules out any potential cluster points there.

Suppose now $x$ is a real such that $x \neq 0 $ and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}: x \neq 1/n$. Then for some $k \in \mathbb{N}: \frac 1{k+1} < x < \frac 1k$.

If I can construct a ball about $x$ with finitely many points from $A$, then that settles it.

Denote $\varepsilon = \frac 12 \min \{ d(x,\frac 1{k+1} ), d(x, \frac 1k)  \}>0$. Observe $B(x,\varepsilon)$ does not intersect $B(\frac 1n, \epsilon)$ for each natural $n$. Nor does $B(x,\varepsilon)$ intersect $B(0,\varepsilon)$

If we have available infinitely many points $r = \frac 1n + \frac 1m \in A$, then either $n$ or $m$ must belong to an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, that is have infinite range.

Given our defined $\varepsilon$ above, the Archimedean property furnishes $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac 1N < \frac {\varepsilon}2$.

For $r  = \frac 1n + \frac 1m \in A$: if $m$ has infinite range then so does $n$. And if $n\geq m\geq N$, we will have $r < \varepsilon$, namely $r \in B(0,\varepsilon)$. So only a finite number of points from $A$ could potentially intersect $B(x,\varepsilon)$.

And if $n$ has infinite range but $m$ finite range: when $n\geq N$ the points $\frac 1n + \frac 1m$ will be inside balls of the kind $B(\frac 1p, \frac {\varepsilon}2)$ and these do not intersect $B(x,\varepsilon)$. Hence, again, only a finite number of points from $A$ could possibly intersect $B(x,\varepsilon)$.

This shows $x$ is not a cluster point of $A$ and ends the proof. $\blacksquare$

---